# SSH: how to modify received characters?

Tags: keyboard, ssh, keyboard-layout

I would like to configure my Ubuntu server(without X Windows) to modify escape characters **received from the SSH clients**. Because by some reasons I can't modify original keystrokes on the remote client.

1. I have root access to the Server machine. Console access as well as SSH.
2. OpenSSH is installed there. But it is ok to replace it with something different if needed.

To be more specific. I would like, for example, to exchange Ctrl and F10, so F10+c is recognized as a Ctrl+c.

Thanks in advance!

P.S. Please, don't suggest any solutions based on modification of client machine. Let's assume I don't have access to the client machine.

Answer (score 1):

When the user "john" logs in through `ssh`, it is given a shell --- depending on your configuration this can be different, but by default is their default shell, which by default is `bash`.(1)

`bash` will execute all the standard init files: basically `/etc/profile`, and the `.profile` in `/home/john`. You can add keymap entries to any of these files (the first one is under superuser control, the latter is under john's control).

See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200800/in-bash-how-do-i-bind-a-function-key-to-a-command

Now, Ctrl-C is quite a low-level function, going straight through sending a signal to the running process. I do not know if you can remap it.

(1) not for me, for example; I have `zsh` as default shell. YMMV.

Comment: Do I understand correctly, I will have to remap it in all programs I run too, not the bash only? In example in Vim and Emacs.

Comment: I think so. Ssh see just characters --- the map between the keys you press and the characters sent is a client stuff, not server. I mean, after you press the key with the label "A" the client send to the server the ASCII/utf8/whatever code for character "A" --- it has no way to know which key exactly generated it. And putting a filter between the client and the (receiving) shell is, well, not a good idea --- if you receive a "ctrl-c" (break) char, how do you know if it's part of a binary blob of data or the user pressed ctrl-c?

Comment: Well, F10 is a quite specific and long escape sequence. I think it is possible to simply replace it with "ctrl" sequence, and it will be more or less safe. Anyway, I agree with you, it would be a dirty hack.